# Have anyone found beautiful way to replace "smth if smth.present?"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, format

Often I'm facing lines like

```
result = 'Some text'
result += some_text_variable if some_text_variable.present?
```

And every time I want to replace that with something more accurate but I don't know how

Any ideas plz?

Comment: You could shave a few characters by doing
`result += var unless !!var`

Comment: @RyanRoberts `!!var` != `var.present?` Please [look](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/09/11/differences-between-nil-empty-blank-and-present.html)

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your code. It is straightforward, easy to read, and easy to understand.

Comment: _"smth if smth.present?"_ – note that the modifier-`if` in your example applies to the _whole_ left-hand side, not just the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result += some_text_variable.to_s
```

It will work if `some_text_variable` is `nil` or empty string for example

But it always will concat empty string to original string

You can also use

```
result += some_text_variable.presence.to_s
```

It will work for all presence cases (for example for `"   "` string)

Answer (score 0):

You could "compact" and join an array, *e.g.*

```
['Some text', some_text_variable].select(&:present?).join
```

I realise this is a longhand form, just offering as an alternative to mutating strings.

This can look a bit nicer, if you have a large number of variables to munge together, or you want to join them in some other way *e.g.*

```
[
  var_1, 
  var_2,
  var_3,
  var_4
].select(&:present?).join("\n")
```

Again, nothing gets mutated - which may or may not suit your coding style.